# Why isn't page used as the unit when calculating the maximum size of RAM a CPU can address?

Tags: memory, cpu

Wikipedia says

> A page, memory page, or virtual page is a fixed-length contiguous
>   block of virtual memory, described by a single entry in the page
>   table. It is the smallest unit of data for memory allocation performed
>   by the operating system on behalf of a program, and for transfers
>   between the main memory and any other auxiliary store, such as a hard
>   disk drive.
>
> ...
>
> Page size is usually determined by processor architecture.
>   Traditionally, pages in a system had uniform size, for example 4096
>   bytes. However, processor designs often allow two or more, sometimes
>   simultaneous, page sizes due to the benefits and penalties.

We know that a 32-bit CPU can address maximum 2^32 bytes = 4 GiB memory.
Why is byte used as the unit in the calculation instead of page?

If a page is  4096 bytes, then a 32-bit CPU can address much larger memory.

Do I miss or misunderstand something?

Comment: It is not the case that a 32-bit CPU can only address a maximum of 2^32 bytes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the cpu does not address a whole page at a time; it addresses each and every individual byte.  The page is simply the unit that the is used to *allocate* memory and set permissions on it.  Also that wikipedia article has an error: disk IO is *not* done in page units either; it is done in sectors, which conventionally is 512 bytes.

Comment: I think the bit about "smallest unit for data transfer" is referring to transferring virtual memory into and out of physical memory (i.e. swapping happens in units of whole pages, you can't swap in/out part of a page)

Answer (score 1):

In the old days mainframe memory was described as so many words. Where words were defined by the hardware ( 18,20,30,32,60,... bits). When minis and PCs arrived, memory was described by bytes ( 4K all the way to 64K ).  Now we have a lot more memory and it is still described by the number of bytes. What you say is true and pages may be a better method of describing it.
As you say a 32 bit CPU can address 4GBs of memory.  Any more and it must be done by paging. It is efficient to use paging for managing memory.  The page size may vary in different OSs, so bytes is still the only way to know the actual amount of memory ( with having to know the page size).  Mostly I think it just the way it has always been done.

Comment: Byte-addressable memory long predated "minis and PCs" - see IBM System/360 for the most famous example. And, paging has nothing directly to do with addressing more RAM than your CPU's "bit width". You're thinking of _address translation_. Granted that paging and address translation generally go together, but they're separate mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page is wrong, or at best misleading, in a couple of details.

> It is the smallest unit of data for memory allocation performed by the operating system on behalf of a program

Correct only for those memory allocation calls that work in units of pages. In Windows, for example, this would be VirtualAlloc. But the heap management routines can certainly operate on smaller increments. (And before someone says "but that's not the operating system, the heap routines are all in user space", consider that there is a kernel space heap too... and some things that programs do from user mode require the OS to allocate kernel heap... and the kernel heap allocations aren't in page-sized strides.)

> and for transfers between the main memory and any other auxiliary store, such as a hard disk drive.

This is not true either. It's true for transfers due to *paging*. But the disk and disk controller can handle transfers of just one block, which traditionally has meant 512 bytes. The claim any "other auxiliary storage" compounds the offense: Tape drives can handle reads and writes of nearly arbitrary block lengths.

As the other answerers correctly stated, the CPU addresses bytes, and the number of bits available for addresses therefore determines the number of *bytes* that can be addressed.